# Use if function to set value of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsstring

Having a little trouble with this after trying to turn my Android app into a iOS app:

This is a sample block of Java code:

```
String temperature;
int x,y;

if (x > y){
temperature = "Increased";
}

else {
temperature = "Decreased";
}

System.out.println (temperature);
```

Now say I wanted to write this in Objective-C, what I'm currently doing is:

```
NSString *temperature = @"Something is not working";
int x,y;

if (x > y){
temperature = "Increased";
}

else {
temperature = "Decreased";
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I apologise if this is blindingly obvious. I've tried to search this up, but evidently, I'm asking the wrong question (have tried searching NSString, NSMutableString, how to overwrite NSString using if function etc).

Comment: Prefix the string with @ to indicate that it is an `NSString` not a C-String - `temperature=@"Increased";`

Comment: Also, you don't need to set a value to temperature as you assign it like "something is not working". You can start with [[NSString alloc] init], which may not also needed if you use [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"..."] while you are assigning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code (1) being that you have `-` before `NSString` not sure why you have this but it isn't needed and (2) when creating a string like you are the most common why is to use the string literal like `@"some string"` notice that the string has been prefixed with the `@` character.

So lets clean your code up.

```
// Not going to preset this because that value would never actually get used.
NSString *temperature; // Notice no "-"
int x, y;

if (x > y) {
    // Notice the String literal prefixed with @
    temperature = @"Increased";
} else {
    // Notice the String literal prefixed with @
    temperature = @"Decreased";
} 

// NSLog is the equivalent to System.out.println 
NSLog(@"The temperature has %@", temperature);
```

Note that in your code and in the cleaned up code the else part of the `if statement` will always be reached because `x` and `y` are the same.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Popeye . Very clear and lucid. =)

Quick question about something I don't quite get: 

This line: 
NSLog(@"The temperature has %@", temperature);

What would be the function of the %@ , and how would I apply that if I had more than 1 string I wanted to call in the NSLog? Would I just use %@ for all of them, and specify which string I was calling after that, separated by commas?

Comment: @TheveshTheva all that `%@` is for in the `NSLog` is kind of like a placeholder that will be replaced by your parameter `temperature`. If you had multiple strings that you wanted to add that is perfectly fine as well you'd just add more `%@` and then add the parameters in the order they should appear. Have a look at http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_String_Objects_in_Objective-C as that may help you understand better

Answer (score 2):

Your code is ok just need little modification. Use `@` sign before string.

```
NSString *temperature = @"Something is not working";
int x,y;

if (x > y){
    temperature = @"Increased";
}

else {
    temperature = @"Decreased";
}
```

> UPDATE

You don't need to initialise the `temperature` variable as you have an `else` part, means your `temperature` variable will always override by the new value.

```
NSString *temperature;
int x,y;

if (x > y){
    temperature = @"Increased";
}
else {
    temperature = @"Decreased";
}
```

Comment: I totally disagree with one statement in this answer and that is `"Your code is ok"` as it is **NOT** OK

Comment: :) you just pick few words from a sentence whose meaning is totally different.  What about `"need little modification"`

Comment: Ok lets look at the whole sentence `"Your code is ok just need little modification"`. Hmmm I still disagree because of `"Your code is ok"` even with the end on it you are still telling the OP their code is OK when it is not. `"just need a little modification"` says that it just needs some improvements, but that is what will make there code OK. It isn't OK it clearly isn't OK. This `"Your code is ok just need little modification."` makes your answer incorrect because of `"Your code is ok"` that little bit. It should just be `"Your code just needs a little modification to be OK"`.

Comment: Also the sentence contradicts itself by saying its OK then saying it needs a little modification. If it needs a little modification it is not OK.

Comment: When someone post something that means it's not correct 100%, they are facing some problem thats why there are here. Same thing, he did it in a right way just unfortunately miss the `@` sign... So whats your problem if I say you code is OK. Cause he is technically correct.

Comment: No it is not technically correct or OK. If it was OK then there would be (1) no need to ask a question (2) no need for you to provide an answer as you can just say in a comment that their code is OK. Wording is very important as you can mislead people by saying `"oh your codes ok"`. I Disagreed because of you saying it was OK, I haven't downvoted as it was a minor error that could easily be fixed. And I never said the rest of your answer was wrong I just said I disagreed with that one bit.